# How to Cause a One-Time Pagebreak in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, tocloft

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage  
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\large} 
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vspace{5pt}} 
%\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\dotfill}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{PART I.}}} \hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 12pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{\emph{SUBTITLE}.}}} \hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 8pt \par}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 36pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{PART II.}}} \hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 12pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{\emph{SUBTITLE}.}}} \hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 8pt \par}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 36pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{PART III.}}} \hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 12pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{\emph{SUBTITLE}.}}} \hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 8pt \par}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 36pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{PART IV.}}} \hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 12pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{\emph{SUBTITLE}.}}} \hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 8pt \par}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 36pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{PART V.}}} \hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 12pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{\emph{SUBTITLE}.}}} \hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 8pt \par}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 36pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{PART VI.}}} \hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 12pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{\emph{SUBTITLE}.}}} \hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 8pt \par}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

I would like to force a pagebreak in the TOC immediately before PART VI. so that the heading ``PART VI.'' (along with its subtitle) both appear at the top of a new page in the TOC. How may I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You can add a `\nopagebreak` before the second `\hfil`, this way your `PART xx` won't be separated from the title. If you are configuring ToC with `tocloft`, you may need to modify the configuration accordingly.

Comment: @Jinwen I tried `\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{PART V.}}} \nopagebreak\hfil}` but I get the error message: Tex capacity exceeded.

Comment: I cannot replicate your error, can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: @Jinwen I repositioned `\nopagebreak` adjacent to `\protect` and the MWE code now compiles without error. Thank you.

Comment: egreg hints at this, but is there a reason you're not using `\part{Subtitle}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you really filling in data for the TOC manually?

Before starting to find a solution, let's fix the really wrong parts you have:

1. `\protect{` is completely useless
2. `\par` after `\vskip` is completely useless
3. you should use `\centering` instead of `\hfil`
4. `\Large{\textbf{\emph{SUBTITLE}.` should better be

   ```
   \Large\bfseries\itshape SUBTITLE
   ```

   (I'd remove the period)

Of course you should define a command that does the job. The key is to add `\nopagebreak` after the `\par` command ending the top line.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\parttocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    % top line
    {\centering\Large\bfseries PART #1\par\nopagebreak}%
    % space
    \vspace{12pt}%
    % bottom line
    {\centering\Large\bfseries\itshape #2\par}%
    % space
    \protect\addvspace{46pt plus 20pt}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\parttocentry{I}{SUBTITLE}
\parttocentry{II}{SUBTITLE}
\parttocentry{III}{SUBTITLE}
\parttocentry{IV}{SUBTITLE}
\parttocentry{V}{SUBTITLE}
\parttocentry{VI}{SUBTITLE}

\end{document}
```

I used 46pt to show that if `\nopagebreak` is removed, the entry for part V would be split across pages.

The vertical space following the entries should be rubber, so to fill the page (because `book` uses `\flushbottom`). You might also add a small amount of shrinkability.

[image]

Note that `\centering` `\Large` `\bfseries` `\itshape` `\vspace` are robust command, but `\addvspace` isn't, so `\protect` is needed in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is your manual simulation of the actual ToC. In order to prevent a page break between the `PART xx` and your title, you can add a `\nopagebreak` (sometimes several) when necessary, like this:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 36pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{PART VI.}}} \nopagebreak\hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 12pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{\emph{SUBTITLE}.}}} \hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 8pt \par}
```

Then your whole title would be placed on the next page when there is no enough space on the previous page.

[image]

You may need to add this to your configuration of ToC. For example, in my own document class, using `titletoc`, I have the following code:

```
\titlecontents{part}
  [0em]
  {\addvspace{1.5pc}\filcenter\normalfont}
  { \minimalist_apply_title_numbering_style_static:n { \thecontentslabel } \nopagebreak\\\nopagebreak\uppercase}
  {}
  {} % without page number
  [\addvspace{.5pc}]
```

which produces something like this (like in your case, the Roman numero should be placed on the same page with the corresponding title):

[image]

Comment: As noted earlier, `\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{PART V.}}} \nopagebreak\hfil}` produces an error message. Perhaps you might modify the MWE code with your ideas into a working example. Many thanks.

Comment: @mlchristians It is working on my side, otherwise I wouldn't be able to get the first screenshot. Could you add a new MWE to your question that can produce the error you mentioned?

Comment: Thank you; as noted in my comment above, I repositioned `\nopagebreak` adjacent to `protect` and I now get no errors.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your helpful suggestion.